# vertical align bottom and top in same container

Tags: javascript, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to put text on top and img in bottom in the container.
  align bottom isnt working

```
<th id="ship_method"  colspan="1" rowspan="1">
<div style="vertical-align:top;">Ship Method</div>
<div style="vertical-align:bottom;">
<img  src="unsortImg.png">
</div>
</th>
```

Comment: try to make them `display: inline` also

Answer (score 1):

The `vertical-align` style only applies to the container element (in this case the `<th>`), not the element you're trying to align. So you can't use `vertical-align` to align two elements differently in the same container.

Instead, you can use absolute positioning to place your two elements in the top and bottom. Be sure to make your container `position:relative`. Check out the demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/8qUeD/**

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @tb11's answer: There is a good change you don't need to actually align your texts like this, but just have them look like they are.

Considering the "lower" content is an image, you could include it as a background image instead and add padding, to that the text doesn't overlap it.

Alternatively, tell us, what is the bigger picture here? What is your overall design? What are the contents/images you want to display here? Is this actually a data table or are you using the table for layout? If you give more details like this, we can give better suggestions.